# dev site reverts to production site url when clearing cache

Tags: caching, uri, migrations, configuration

I have moved a copy of my production site to a development box. When I clear cache at `admin/settings/performance` or save settings on a theme, all of a sudden the URL jumps from `localhost/example/admin/build/themes/settings/theme` to `www.example.com/admin/build/themes/settings/theme` for instance. I have cleared all of my cache tables manually via phpmyadmin and for the browser (chrome, cleared everything "from the beginning of time"). I can't successfully run cron .

EDIT: If I had enough reputation, I would downvote myself. I had the "base url" setting enabled in settings.php.

Comment: Random guess...secure pages installed and an https RedirectRule in the .htaccess?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with all the Drupal configs, so I'd do a search of `example.com` in the database dump file and in the source code of the enclosing project in this situation. Times when `Ctrl`+`H` in Eclipse comes in handy.

Comment: Based on your edit, I think you should answer your own question.  That way, it will not show up as unanswered.  I am not sure whether you are allowed to accept your own answer ...

Comment: Hah, I was going to suggest your answer before I got to it - I have done that more than once! Also, yes, answer your own question and after a while you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Clive's suggestion jarred my memory and I figured it out. I have a multisite setup that I was migrating and had the `base url` setting in settings.php set to `www.example.com` and I had forgotten to change it to the localhost url. When I commented out the base url setting, everything was fine.